# why my response payload not getting parsed properly in django restframework?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I have below code:

```
class MergeCompanyDetails(APIView):
     @staticmethod
     def get(_, id=None):
            api_log(msg="Processing GET request in MergeAccounts...")
            comp__id_client = Basic(base_url=settings.BASE_URL, token=settings.TOKEN, key=settings.KEY)

            try:
                organization_data = comp__id_client.account.info.retrieve(id=id, expand=CompanyInfo.XYZ)
                print('[organization_data1] :::', organization_data)
            except Exception as e:
                api_log(
                    msg=f"Error retrieving organizations details: {str(e)} - Status Code: {status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR}: {traceback.format_exc()}")
                return Response({'error': str(e)}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)

            # Create the payload dynamically from organization_data
            formatted_addresses = [
                {
                    "type": addr.type,
                    "street_1": addr.street_1,
                    "street_2": addr.street_2,
                    "city": addr.city,
                    "state": addr.state,
                    "country_subdivision": addr.country_subdivision,
                    "country": addr.country,
                    "zip_code": addr.zip_code,
                    "created_at": addr.created_at,
                    "modified_at": addr.modified_at,
                } for addr in organization_data.addresses
            ]

            phone_types = [
                {
                    "number": phone.number,
                    "type": phone.type,
                    "created_at": phone.created_at,
                    "modified_at": phone.modified_at,
                } for phone in organization_data.phone_numbers
            ]
            formatted_data = []
            for org_tup in organization_data:
                organization = dict(org_tup[0])
                print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@", organization)
                formatted_entry = {
                    "id": organization.get("id"),
                    "remote": organization.get("remote"),
                    "addresses": formatted_addresses,
                    "phone_numbers": phone_types,
                }
                formatted_data.append(formatted_entry)

            api_log(msg=f"FORMATTED DATA: {formatted_data} - Status Code: {status.HTTP_200_OK}: {traceback.format_exc()}")
            return Response(formatted_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

when I simply print the `organization_data`, I get below output in the IDE console

```
id='a5945ed8-932d-4c9d-9090-e8a50c58fbb6' remote_id='3f03913f-d173-4aa9-a7d8-cf8fc0525fa4' addresses=[Address(type=None, street_1='23 Main Street', street_2='Central City', city='Marinevill
e', state='', country_subdivision='', country=None, zip_code='12345', created_at=datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 16, 6, 44, 57, 937035, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), modified_at=datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 16, 6, 44, 57, 937052, tzinfo=date
time.timezone.utc))] phone_numbers=[AccountingPhoneNumber(number='1234 5678', type='OFFICE', created_at=datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 16, 6, 44, 57, 965582, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), modified_at=datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 16, 6, 44, 
57, 965600, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc))]
```

when I do a for loop as below

```
organization_data = comp__id_client.account.info.retrieve(id=id, expand=CompanyInfo.XYZ)
for key in organization_data:
    print(key)
```

I see below sample output in my IDE console

```
('id', 'a5945ed8-932d-4c9d-9090-e8a50c58fbb6')
('remote_id', '3f03913f-d173-4aa9-a7d8-cf8fc0525fa4')
('addresses', [Address(type=None, street_1='23 Main Street', street_2='Central City', city='Marineville', state='', country_subdivision='', country=None, zip_code='12345', created_at=datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 16, 6, 44, 57, 937035, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), modified_at=datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 16, 6, 44, 57, 937052, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc))])
('phone_numbers', [AccountingPhoneNumber(number='1234 5678', type='OFFICE', created_at=datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 16, 6, 44, 57, 965582, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), modified_at=datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 16, 6, 44, 57, 965600, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc))])
```

The output seems to be individual tuple of key and value pair.

There is no issues with the overall program, The issue is with the response payload that I have created. I have below structure from the POSTMAN

```
{
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": "a5945ed8-932d",
            "remote": "3f03913f-d173",
            "urls": [],
            "addresses": [
                {
                    "type": null,
                    "street_1": "23 Main Street",
                    "street_2": "Central City",
                    "city": "Marineville",
                    "state": "",
                    "country_subdivision": "",
                    "country": null,
                    "zip_code": "12345",
                    "created_at": "2024-01-16T06:44:57.937035Z",
                    "modified_at": "2024-01-16T06:44:57.937052Z"
                }
            ],
            "phone_numbers": [
                {
                    "number": "1234 5678",
                    "type": "OFFICE",
                    "created_at": "2024-01-16T06:44:57.965582Z",
                    "modified_at": "2024-01-16T06:44:57.965600Z"
                }
            ],
            "remote_was_deleted": false,
            "created_at": "2024-01-16T06:44:57.908319Z",
            "modified_at": "2024-01-16T06:44:57.908337Z",
            "field_mappings": {
                "organization_defined_targets": {},
                "linked_account_defined_targets": {}
            },
            "remote_data": null
        }
    ]
}
```

As per the above POSTMAN structure, I have designed the response payload which is already present in the main program at the top.

But I am getting below error

```
    organization = dict(org_tup[1])
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Then I tried removing the dict() and call the payload as below

```
            "id": organization.id,
            "remote": organization.remote,
```

But it started to give below error

```
    "id": organization.id,
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Not able to figure out the root cause. Please suggest, Thank you